# Group date by week at one month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want grouping data by week at one month 
Here my sql code :

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(b.totmom), 0) AS mom,  
  a.monthLead
FROM (SELECT 'Week 1' monthLead, 
    1 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Week 2' monthLead, 
    2 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Week 3' monthLead, 
    3 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Week 4' monthLead, 
    4 monthOrder UNION ALL SELECT 'Week 5' monthLead, 
    5 monthOrder) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.momDate, COUNT(b.momID) as totmom, 
  FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1) week
FROM log_mom b 
WHERE YEAR(b.momDate)='2019'
  AND MONTH(b.momDate)='06' 
  AND FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1) IN ('Week 1','Week 2','Week 3','Week 4','Week 5') 
group by week ) b ON a.monthLead = FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1) GROUP BY a.monthLead ORDER BY a.monthOrder");
```

sample data table log_mom  :

```
momID momDate
 1    2019-06-01
 2    2019-06-03
 3    2019-06-03
 4    2019-06-07
 5    2019-06-12
 6    2019-06-14
 7    2019-06-23
 8    2019-06-24
 9    2019-06-29
 10   2019-06-31
```

and the result is :

```
mom monthLead
 0   Week 1
```

how i can get the result like this :

```
mom monthLead
 4   Week 1
 2   Week 2
 0   Week 3
 2   Week 4
 2   Week 5
```

Comment: Please include sample data for all tables involved.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats the sample data

Comment: The data you added does not help much to make your question easier to understand.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i only want count how much id at 1 month but group by week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a confusion among intger value (`monthOrder`) and string (`monthLead`) as `JOIN` condition, and `GROUP BY a.monthLead` is missing for the main query, and filter condition `AND FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1)...` seems wrong  :

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(b.totmom), 0) AS mom, a.monthLead
  FROM (
        SELECT 'Week 1' monthLead, 1 monthOrder UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Week 2' monthLead, 2 monthOrder UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Week 3' monthLead, 3 monthOrder UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Week 4' monthLead, 4 monthOrder UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Week 5' monthLead, 5 monthOrder                        
        ) a
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.momDate,
                    COUNT(b.momID) as totmom,
                    FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1) week
               FROM log_mom b
              WHERE YEAR(b.momDate) = '2019'
                AND MONTH(b.momDate) = '06'
             -- AND FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1) IN ('Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5')
              GROUP BY week) b
    ON a.monthOrder = FLOOR(((DAY(b.momDate) - 1) / 7) + 1)
 GROUP BY a.monthLead;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ba4e667845cfe1d05e6cd52ac5d4ecdd)</kbd>

Comment: thanks its work, i forget include this `GROUP BY a.monthLead` at my query